# Bring out other property of crafting item

Tags: enchanted-cave-2

In Enchanted Cave 2, each Crafting Item has two distinct Properties, concerning what they can do when enchanting a weapon or making a potion.

No matter what I do, it's always one of the properties that counts, i.e. actually affects the enchantment or potion,  for each Crafting Item type.

The other property might as well not exist, but it's there on display! Is there a way to activate them?

As a concrete example, a Turtle Shell could provide Ice Defence or Earth Defence in theory, but in practice it's always Earth Defence. Can it be made to provide Ice Defence?

If not, why is the second Property there??

Link to game: http://armorgames.com/play/17682/the-enchanted-cave-2

Link to wiki about items: http://theenchantedcave.wikia.com/wiki/Items_(TEC2)

Answer (score 0):

broken fixer is right.

It's a little confusing at first. In craft mode, the latest item is always selected from the bottom. When clicking through more than one at the top under ingredients, you will need to click on the later one to select it.

Switching equipment is also annoyingly confusing compared to polished games like Diablo however, we still love TEC2 :)

Answer (score -1):

Click on the other property using the mouse.

Comment: What exactly does this do? Can you elaborate more?